# Drag and lift force acting on an airfoil

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, finite-element-method

To calculate force acting on an airfoil we can use FEM with version 12 and over. Here we show an example with NACA2415. First we calculate mesh and potential flow:

```
ClearAll[NACA2415];
NACA2415[{m_, p_, t_}, x_] := 
  Module[{}, 
   yc = Piecewise[{{m/p^2 (2 p x - x^2), 
       0 <= x < p}, {m/(1 - p)^2 ((1 - 2 p) + 2 p x - x^2), 
       p <= x <= 1}}];
   yt = 5 t (0.2969 Sqrt[x] - 0.1260 x - 0.3516 x^2 + 0.2843 x^3 - 
       0.1015 x^4);
   \[Theta] = 
    ArcTan@Piecewise[{{(m*(2*p - 2*x))/p^2, 
        0 <= x < p}, {(m*(2*p - 2*x))/(1 - p)^2, p <= x <= 1}}];
   {{x - yt Sin[\[Theta]], 
     yc + yt Cos[\[Theta]]}, {x + yt Sin[\[Theta]], 
     yc - yt Cos[\[Theta]]}}];

m = 0.02;
pp = 0.4;
tk = 0.15;
pe = NACA2415[{m, pp, tk}, x];
ParametricPlot[pe, {x, 0, 1}, ImageSize -> Large, Exclusions -> None]

ClearAll[myLoop];
myLoop[n1_, n2_] := 
 Join[Table[{n, n + 1}, {n, n1, n2 - 1, 1}], {{n2, n1}}]
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];(*angle of attack*)alpha = -Pi/32;
rt = RotationTransform[alpha];
a = Table[
  pe, {x, 0, 1, 0.01}];(*table of coordinates around aerofoil*)
p0 = {pp, tk/2};(*point inside aerofoil*)
x1 = -1; x2 = 2;(*domain dimensions*)
y1 = -1; y2 = 1;(*domain dimensions*)
coords = Join[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x1, y2}}, 
  rt@a[[All, 2]], rt@Reverse[a[[All, 1]]]];
nn = Length@coords;
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh["Coordinates" -> coords, 
   "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[myLoop[1, 4]], 
     LineElement[myLoop[5, nn]]}, "RegionHoles" -> {rt@p0}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh, AccuracyGoal -> 5, PrecisionGoal -> 5, 
   "MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.0005, "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 0.01];
ClearAll[x, y, ϕ];
sol = NDSolveValue[{D[ϕ[x, y], x, x] + D[ϕ[x, y], y, y] == 
     NeumannValue[1, x == x1 && y1 <= y <= y2] + 
      NeumannValue[-1, x == x2 && y1 <= y <= y2], 
    DirichletCondition[ϕ[x, y] == 0, 
     x == 0 && y == 0]}, ϕ, {x, y} ∈ mesh];
ClearAll[vel];
vel = Evaluate[Grad[sol[x, y], {x, y}]];
```

Now we use potential flow as a boundary condition for viscous flow

```
bcs = {
   DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 1, v[x, y] == 0}, x == x1], 
   DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == vel[[1]], v[x, y] == vel[[2]]}, 
    y == y1 || y == y2 ], 
   DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 0., v[x, y] == 0.}, 0 <= x <= 1],
   DirichletCondition[{p[x, y] == 1}, x == x2]};

op = {Inactive[Div][{{-μ, 0}, {0, -μ}} . Inactive[Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] + 
      ρ*{{u[x, y], v[x, y]}} . Inactive[Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}] + Derivative[1, 0][p][x, y], 
     Inactive[Div][{{-μ, 0}, {0, -μ}} . Inactive[Grad][v[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] + 
      ρ*{{u[x, y], v[x, y]}} . Inactive[Grad][v[x, y], {x, y}] + Derivative[0, 1][p][x, y], 
     Derivative[1, 0][u][x, y] + Derivative[0, 1][v][x, y]} /. {μ -> 10^(-3), ρ -> 1}; 
pde = op == {0, 0, 0}; {xVel, yVel, pressure} = NDSolveValue[{pde, bcs}, {u, v, p}, 
    Element[{x, y}, mesh], Method -> {"FiniteElement", "InterpolationOrder" -> 
       {u -> 2, v -> 2, p -> 1}}];
```

Visualization of flow velocity and pressure

```
    {Show[ContourPlot[Norm[{xVel[x, y], yVel[x, y]}], 
   Element[{x, y}, mesh], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
   PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic, Epilog -> {Line[coords[[5 ;; nn]]]}, 
   Contours -> 20], 
  StreamPlot[{xVel[x, y], yVel[x, y]}, Element[{x, y}, mesh], 
   StreamStyle -> LightGray, AspectRatio -> Automatic]], 
 ContourPlot[pressure[x, y], Element[{x, y}, mesh], 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  Epilog -> {Line[coords[[5 ;; nn]]]}, Contours -> 20]}
```

[image: Figure 1]

Finally we calculate force

```
ydw = Interpolation[Take[coords[[5 ;; nn]], 101]]; yup = 
 Interpolation[Take[coords[[5 ;; nn]], -101]];
force = With[{umean = 1, Y2 = ydw'[x], 
    Y1 = yup'[x], ρ = 1, μ = 10^-3, dux = D[xVel[x, y], x], 
    duy = D[xVel[x, y], y], dvx = D[yVel[x, y], x], 
    dvy = D[yVel[x, y], y]}, 
   Function[X, Block[{x, y, nx, ny, fx, fy, p},
     {x, y} = X;
     p = pressure[x, y];
     nx = If[y > x Tan[alpha], -Y1/Sqrt[1 + Y1^2], Y2/Sqrt[1 + Y2^2]];
     ny = If[y > x Tan[alpha], 1/Sqrt[1 + Y1^2], -1/Sqrt[1 + Y2^2]];
     fx = nx*p + μ*(-2*nx*dux - ny*(duy + dvx));
     fy = ny*p + μ*(-nx*(dvx + duy) - 2*ny*dvy);
     {fx, fy}
     ]]];



    {fdrag, flift} = 
 NIntegrate[force[{x, y}], {x, y} \[Element] Line[coords[[5 ;; nn]]], 
   AccuracyGoal -> 3, PrecisionGoal -> 3] // AbsoluteTiming

(*Out[]= {96.6227, {-0.0809347, -0.139907}}*)
```

The question is about time for `NIntegrate`. In tutorial example for cylinder it is only 0.5 s. And here 96.6227 on my machine. Can we reduce this time?

Update 1. I have tested code by user21 and try to compare with code by Tim Laska. I have realized that both codes are good, but my code not applicable to the airfoil NACA9415 that I used as a first test example. Now we can compare code by user21 with code by Tim Laska:

```
 bmeshFoil = 
  ToBoundaryMesh["Coordinates" -> coords[[5 ;; nn]], 
   "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[
      Partition[Range[Length[coords[[5 ;; nn]]]], 2, 1, 1]]}];

 {fdrag, flift} = 
 NIntegrate[force[{x, y}], {x, y} \[Element] bmeshFoil, 
   AccuracyGoal -> 3, PrecisionGoal -> 3] // AbsoluteTiming

(*Out[]= {1.05284, {-0.0811379, -0.141117}}*)
```

And second code

```
bn = bmeshFoil["BoundaryNormals"];
mean = Mean /@ GetElementCoordinates[bmeshFoil["Coordinates"], #] & /@
    ElementIncidents[bmeshFoil["BoundaryElements"]];
dist = EuclideanDistance @@@ 
     GetElementCoordinates[bmeshFoil["Coordinates"], #] & /@ 
   ElementIncidents[bmeshFoil["BoundaryElements"]];
ids = Flatten@
   Position[
    Flatten[mean, 1], _?(EuclideanDistance[#, {0, 0}] < 1.1 &), 1];
foilbn = bn[[1, ids]];
foilbnplt = ArrayReshape[foilbn, {1}~Join~(foilbn // Dimensions)];
foildist = dist[[1, ids]];
foildistplt = 
  ArrayReshape[foildist, {1}~Join~(foildist // Dimensions)];
foilmean = mean[[1, ids]];
foilmeanplt = 
  ArrayReshape[foilmean, {1}~Join~(foilmean // Dimensions)];
Show[bmesh["Wireframe"], 
 Graphics[MapThread[
   Arrow[{#1, #2}] &, {Join @@ foilmeanplt, 
    Join @@ (foilbnplt/5 + foilmeanplt)}]]]



ClearAll[fluidStress]
fluidStress[{uif_InterpolatingFunction, vif_InterpolatingFunction, 
   pif_InterpolatingFunction}, mu_, rho_, bn_, dist_, mean_] := 
 Block[{dd, df, mesh, coords, dv, press, fx, fy, wfx, wfy, nx, ny, ux,
    uy, vx, vy}, duu = Evaluate[Grad[uif[x, y], {x, y}]]; 
  dvv = Evaluate[Grad[vif[x, y], {x, y}]];
  (*the coordinates from the foil*)coords = mean;
  ux = duu[[1]] /. {x -> coords[[All, 1]], y -> coords[[All, 2]]};
  uy = duu[[2]] /. {x -> coords[[All, 1]], y -> coords[[All, 2]]};
  vx = dvv[[1]] /. {x -> coords[[All, 1]], y -> coords[[All, 2]]};
  vy = dvv[[2]] /. {x -> coords[[All, 1]], y -> coords[[All, 2]]};
  nx = bn[[All, 1]];
  ny = bn[[All, 2]];
  press = pif[#1, #2] & @@@ coords;
  fx = Sum[
    dist[[i]] (nx[[i]]*press[[i]] + 
       mu*(-2*nx[[i]]*ux[[i]] - ny[[i]]*(uy[[i]] + vx[[i]]))), {i, 
     Length[dist]}];
  fy = Sum[
    dist[[i]] (ny[[i]]*press[[i]] + 
       mu*(-2*ny[[i]]*vy[[i]] - nx[[i]]*(uy[[i]] + vx[[i]]))), {i, 
     Length[dist]}];
        {fx, fy}]
```

Now we can compare 2 results and find that all close to my code but faster in more than 100 times.

```
AbsoluteTiming[{fdrag, flift} = 
  fluidStress[{xVel, yVel, pressure}, 10^-3, 1, bn[[1]], foildist, 
   foilmean]]

(*Out[]= {0.382285, {-0.0798489, -0.139879}}*)
```

Comment: Where you do `{x, y} ∈ Line[coords[[5 ;; nn]]]` if we replace this with a few simple lines such as the border of a square, it takes just a few seconds. So it's the complexity of the shape and the number of lines that's the biggest problem. The aerofoil has lots of small lines which could be combined into a single large line where it is mostly flat on the upper surface, while the leading edge needs more lines. This amounts to a kind of mesh decimation problem.

Comment: @flinty Do you mean that impossibly to improve this code?

Comment: I profiled it and just about everything else was pretty fast. So it's mostly the NIntegrate that's the problem. Some coordinates in the aerofoil shape could be dropped because the shape is mostly flat there. This would speed up the integral.

Comment: @flinty Is it mean that we should abandoned `NIntegrate`?

Comment: No I never said that. I mean you should look at the region `Line[coords[[5 ;; nn]]]` more closely - there are many lines which could be sacrificed, and replaced with longer lines where the shape is flat - the large number of lines is what's making `NIntegrate` slow.

Comment: @flinty In what version you tested this code? See answer by user21. He got some message in 12.0.0 and 12.1.1 for Linux.

Comment: I tested on 12.1.1 Windows 10.

Comment: Thanks Alex for harmonizing the two codes and running the comparison.  I didn't think the two methods should be too different.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When I run your code I get a `FindRoot` warning message:

[image]

Which makes me suspicious of the result quality. If we assume the result is correct we can speed up the integration by using the FEM for that too. We create a boundary element mesh of the foil:

```
bmeshFoil = 
  ToBoundaryMesh["Coordinates" -> coords[[5 ;; nn]], 
   "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[
      Partition[Range[Length[coords[[5 ;; nn]]]], 2, 1, 1]]}];
```

And integrate along the boundary:

```
{fdrag, flift} = 
 NIntegrate[force[{x, y}], {x, y} \[Element] bmeshFoil, 
   AccuracyGoal -> 3, PrecisionGoal -> 3] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.702661, {0.209457, 1.34502}} *)
```

Comment: In what part you got this message?  I have tested in v.12.0.0 and 12.1.1 for Windows 64 bit, and nothing got. But nevertheless your approach with FEM solves this problem (+1).

Comment: @AlexTrounev, it comes from the second call to NDSolve, the one with the nonlinear equation. I see this on Linux.

Comment: In what version for Linux you seen this message?

Comment: @AlexTrounev, "12.1.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)"

Comment: @AlexTrounev, I also see it in V12.0.0

Comment: Now we can ask flinty and Tim about version.

Comment: Now that Alex has updated his post to compare the two methods, do you think `ToNumericalRegion` would squeeze out some additional accuracy in either case?

Comment: @TimLaska, no, I don't think so. `ToNumericalRegion` is useful when we use ideal graphics primitives which have infinite precision. A `Disk` for example, or boolean operations involving order ideal primitives. In this case we have an inexact region. The lines to not represent the foil to infinite precision. If we can make use of the parametric representation of the foil things might be different.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a partial non-`NIntegrate` answer that still needs work but might give you some ideas on how to proceed.

I extended the domain so that it would be easier for me to pick line segments related to the airfoil.

```
x1 = -2; x2 = 3; y1 = -1.5; y2 = 1.5;(*domain dimensions*)
```

Then I followed this example from the [documentation](https://wolfram.com/xid/0isbpxxk55revfr6uj706fhkk-kktdjv) to grab normals at line segment midpoint and the length of each segment:

```
bn = bmesh["BoundaryNormals"];
mean = Mean /@ GetElementCoordinates[bmesh["Coordinates"], #] & /@ 
   ElementIncidents[bmesh["BoundaryElements"]];
dist = EuclideanDistance @@@ 
     GetElementCoordinates[bmesh["Coordinates"], #] & /@ 
   ElementIncidents[bmesh["BoundaryElements"]];
ids = Flatten@
   Position[
    Flatten[mean, 1], _?(EuclideanDistance[#, {0, 0}] < 1.1 &), 1];
foilbn = bn[[1, ids]];
foilbnplt = ArrayReshape[foilbn, {1}~Join~(foilbn // Dimensions)];
foildist = dist[[1, ids]];
foildistplt = 
  ArrayReshape[foildist, {1}~Join~(foildist // Dimensions)];
foilmean = mean[[1, ids]];
foilmeanplt = 
  ArrayReshape[foilmean, {1}~Join~(foilmean // Dimensions)];
Show[bmesh["Wireframe"], 
 Graphics[MapThread[
   Arrow[{#1, #2}] &, {Join @@ foilmeanplt, 
    Join @@ (foilbnplt/5 + foilmeanplt)}]]]
```

[image: Foil Normals]

It looks like we captured all the normals associated with the airfoil.  You have lots of normals so I think a weighted sum should be a decent approximation to the integral.

Then, I created a function that takes a weighted sum of forces.  It is fast but it needs some work and validation, but this method is similar what is done with other codes.

```
ClearAll[fluidStress]
fluidStress[{uif_InterpolatingFunction, vif_InterpolatingFunction, 
   pif_InterpolatingFunction}, mu_, rho_, bn_, dist_, mean_] := 
 Block[{dd, df, mesh, coords, dv, press, fx, fy, wfx, wfy, nx, ny, ux,
    uy, vx, vy}, 
  dd = Outer[(D[#1[x, y], #2]) &, {uif, vif}, {x, y}];
  df = Table[Function[{x, y}, Evaluate[dd[[i, j]]]], {i, 2}, {j, 2}];
  (*the coordinates from the foil*)
  coords = mean;
  dv = Table[df[[i, j]] @@@ coords, {i, 2}, {j, 2}];
  ux = dv[[1, 1]];
  uy = dv[[1, 2]];
  vx = dv[[2, 1]];
  vy = dv[[2, 2]];
  nx = bn[[All, 1]];
  ny = bn[[All, 2]];
  press = pif[#1, #2] & @@@ coords;
  fx = -nx*press + mu*(-2*nx*ux - ny*(uy + vx));
  fy = -ny*press + mu*(-nx*(vx + uy) - 2*ny*vy);
  wfx = dist*fx ;
  wfy = dist*fy; 
  Total /@ {wfx, wfy}
  ]
AbsoluteTiming[{fdrag, flift} = 
  fluidStress[{xVel, yVel, pressure}, 10^-3, 1, foilbn, foildist, 
   foilmean]]
(* {0.364506, {0.00244262, 0.158859}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It solves my second problem with turbulence model adding (+1). But numbers should be validate compare to my code and with user21 as well.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I think @user21's code is a slick way to go.  I do see the same error that @user21 sees on my extended domain.  I am running `12.1.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)`.  I do get a different result, however, `{1.78533, {-0.0107521, 1.41575}}`.  A lot of the airfoil models that I have seen have pretty large domains relative to the chord length (e.g., 500:1).

Comment: This is a minimal example to go, and not code for commercial applications. On my short domain I have no any messages on 12.0.0 and 12.1.1 for Windows 64 bit.